# Динамический отображение элементов wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 40 изображений (размером 2800x2800) в папке, каждые 10 изображений нужно отобразить в своём блоке (1 полукомплект, 2...).

Раньше использовал просто GRID, разбивал его по колонкам() и каждую картинку закидывал в кнопку c разметкой   , и каждой такой кнопке присваивал элемент коллекции Images[элемент].Image, выглядело ужасно.

Сейчас хочу всё переделать под ListView или аналоги.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Первый полукомлект КСВ"/>
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\polagaev\Desktop\Безымянный.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Файл"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Второй полукомлект КСВ"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Первый полукомлект КСВ"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Второй полукомлект КСВ"/>
        </Grid>
```

Выглядит это вот так:

[image: Форма]

При такой разметке изображение растягивается внутри блока до максимума.

Если укажу фиксированный размер, то все картинки влазят на форму, но они не растягиваются динамически.

```
<DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Width="80" Height="80">
          <Image Source="C:\Users\polagaev\Desktop\Безымянный.png"/>
          <TextBlock Text="Файл"/>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отобразить 10 изображений, чтобы они могли растягиваться и отображались все (без скроллинга и тд)?

По ответу aepot, за что ему большое спасибо, получилось следующее:

[image: Полученный снимок]

А можно ли и по высоте растянуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для 1/10 добавьте перед `ListView` сетку, с шириной первой колонки 1/10, в первую колонку еще один грид, дайте ему имя. И привяжитесь к его ширине для `StackPanel`.

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid x:Name="PartGrid"/>
<Grid>
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PartGrid}">
                <Image Source="C:\Users\polagaev\Desktop\Безымянный.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Файл"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Появляется scroll и изображения всё равно большие, в общем тоже самое что и на 1 скриншоте.

Comment: @Denis обновил ответ, этот фокус всегда работает

Comment: А можно ли и по высоте растягивать тоже?

Comment: @Denis картинка по умолчанию вроде в оригинальных пропорциях должна рисоваться