# WPF ListView & GridView, как сделать автоматическую подгонку всех колонок?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сделать автоматическую подгонку всех столбцов GridView, но ничего не могу найти и сделать сам.
Что хочу: [image: примерно подгонки столбцов]
Нужно, чтобы названия столбцов переносилось, если не хватает места (из примера - Родительская категория), а так же переносился текст (из примера - Корневая категория).
Может я делаю двойную работу и пытаюсь изобрести свой велосипед и уже есть готовое решение? Если нет, то буду рад любым ссылкам и советам куда смотреть.

Comment: [TextBlock text wrapping in GridViewColumn.CellTemplate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11101360/312041) ?

Comment: Ну, решение подойдет если колонкам явно указывать размер, а мне хотелось, чтобы они сами занимали сколько им нужно места

Comment: это два противоречивых требования. С одной стороны, вы хотите, чтобы текст в колонках схлопывался в 2 строки, а с другой, чтобы колонка занимала сколько ей надо. Ей надо столько, чтобы текст умещался в одну строку.

Comment: Не правильно выразился немного)
В конечном итоге хочу, чтобы колонки подбивались на всю доступную ширину пространства (ActualWidth окна, например)

Comment: Есть лайфхак, делаете пустой `Grid`, перед `ListView`, в том же контейнере, делаете ему колонки как обычно, в каждую колонку добавляете еще один пустой `Grid` и даете дочерним гридам имена. Ширину колонок настраиваете в старшем грде как обычно. Далее, ширину колонок привязываете к пустым гридам (`ActualWidth`), и готово. Этот способ достаточно популярен и примеров можно найти много, [в том числе и здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257522/373567).

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как его применить к моему примеру, если честно, там используется ItemTemplate, но он мне не нужен, как я понимаю, у меня используется GridView